# Desire2Learn - Valence Authenication error when updating course info

Tags: desire2learn, valence

When I attempt to update course info I receive a 403 error.  I'm using an adminstrator level account and D2L's test apitest tool. I'm able to pull course info.

API Call: `PUT /d2l/api/lp/1.4/courses/2499625`

JSON PARM: `CourseOfferingInfo`

JSON DATA:

```
{"Name":"Dale.SandBox","Code":"Dale.SandBox","IsActive":true,"StartDate":"2015-07-10T17:20:00.000Z","EndDate":null}
```

Comment: What's in the response body?

Answer (score 0):

You JSON data and parameter looks correct. The only reason the [documentation gives for returning a 403](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/course.html#put--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-courses-%28orgUnitId%29) is if permissions are insufficient. The permissions structure in D2L is so flexible that it's possible that an administrative level account doesn't have permission to update course info in the apitest tool.

One way to check this and practice with the API a bit would be to [GET what permissions](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/permissions.html) your account has.

Comment: Thank you, your anwser was very helpful.  I had to grant the account the ablity to change course path, even though I was not updating it.